# Por que no reconoce la funcion fntSavePermissions?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy intentando utilizar una funcion dentro de otra,con el addEventListener, pero por algun motivo refleja un error que la funcion no esta definida.

```
 function fntPermissions()
    {
        var btnPermissionsRoll = document.querySelectorAll(".btnPermissionsRoll");
        btnPermissionsRoll.forEach(function (btnPermissionsRoll){
           btnPermissionsRoll.addEventListener('click', function (){
               var idroll = this.getAttribute("rl");
               var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
               var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Permissions/getPermissionsRoll/'+idroll;
               request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
               request.send();

               request.onreadystatechange = function (){
                   if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                       document.querySelector('#contentAjax').innerHTML= request.responseText;
                       $('.modalPermissions').modal('show');
                       document.querySelector('#formPermissions').addEventListener('submit',fntSavePermissions,false);
                   }
               }
           });
        });
    }

    function fntSavePermissions(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        var ajaxUrl = base_url+'/Permissions/setPermissions';
        var formElement = document.querySelector('#formPermissions');
        var formData = new FormData(formElement);
        request.open("POST", ajaxUrl,true);
        request.send(formData);
    }
```

Me sale este error en el navegador Uncaught ReferenceError: fntSavePermissions is not defined

Este es el controlador:

```
public function setPermissions()
{
dep ($_POST);
die();

}
```

Este es el formulario

```
<form action="" id="formPermissions" name="formPermissions">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="idroll" name="idroll" value="<?= $data['idroll'];?>" required="">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th>Modul</th>
                                                <th>Read</th>
                                                <th>Write</th>
                                                <th>Update</th>
                                                <th>Delete</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                            <?php
                                                $no=1;
                                                $moduls = $data['moduls'];
                                                for ($i=0; $i < count($moduls); $i++)
                                                {
                                                    $permissions = $moduls[$i]['permissions'];
                                                    $rCheck = $permissions['r'] == 1 ? " checked " : "";
                                                    $wCheck = $permissions['w'] == 1 ? " checked " : "";
                                                    $uCheck = $permissions['u'] == 1 ? " checked " : "";
                                                    $dCheck = $permissions['d'] == 1 ? " checked " : "";

                                                    $idmod = $moduls[$i]['idmodulo'];

                                            ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?= $no; ?>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="moduls[<?= $i ?>][idmodulo]" value="<?= $idmod?>" required="">
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <?= $moduls[$i]['titulo']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                                <td><div class="toggle-flip">
                                                        <label>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" name="moduls[<?= $i; ?>][r]" <?= $rCheck ?>><span class="flip-indecator" data-toggle-on="ON" data-toggle-off="OFF"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
```

La funcion fntSavePermissions la estoy llamando directamente desde la  funcion fntPermissions con el addEventListener. y se ejecuta al utilizar el boton de save que tiene la funcion de submit. Pero de entrada dice que no he definido la funcion de fntSavePermissions y si la defino.

Comment: Pero... y en que contexto la usas? donde defines esa funcion y donde la usas?

Comment: es de un formulario, que tengo. Lo que necesito es que reconozca la funcion para que pueda almacenar la informacion que envio. El archivo esta en la carpeta de js. El formulario es el que tiene el id="formPermissions". Pero el problema es que al entrar al modulo de permissions, aparece el error de: Uncaught ReferenceError: fntSavePermissions is not defined

Comment: Maria, pero compartenos ese código por favor... me dices que el formulario es el que tiene `id="formPermissions"` pero y ese código donde está? Donde está el código desde donde ejecutas la funcion `fntSavePermissions`? agregalo a la pregunta que ahi es donde está el problema. Recuerda que puedes usar el link para [edit]

Comment: ya lo edite, esta el formulario y el controlador. Pero la funcion fntSavePermissions la estoy llamando directamente desde la funcion fntPermissions con el addEventListener. y se ejecuta al utilizar el boton de save que tiene la funcion de submit. Pero de entrada dice que no he definido la funcion de fntSavePermissions y si la defino.

Comment: Puede que el bloque Javascript donde defines a esa función aún no se haya cargado y por eso no la encuentra. Conviene siempre poner todo el código JS dentro del evento `DOMContentLoaded`, intenta definir todas tus funciones dentro de este bloque: **`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    //define aquí fntPermissions, fntSavePermissions y todas las demás funciones
  });`** Para más detalles [consulta la documentación](https://es.javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded).